# What ever I export my modeled weapon to UE4 or Unity I look around and loses edges to another

Tags: modeling

I have problem where I export my gun models into Unreal engine or Unity, as I look around my gun model it loses edges to another (what ever I look to the other side it loses an edge, but when I look to the other side, the other side I just looked at before gets back, and the other side gets lost). This does not happen in blender but in Unreal engine and Unity it does that glitch.
Any ways to try to fix that? I left down images so you know what I mean.

[image: In blender]

[image: In Unreal engine or Unity]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem but it looks like the normals of your faces are pointing in the wrong direction. Blender doesn't cull back faces by default but unity does. To fix it select your model, go into edit mode, select all faces, and press SHIFT N

Comment: Thanks man it did help me fix my problem, although that it's a bit complicated but I will get the hang of it. :)

Comment: You should look into backface culling and face normal orientation

Comment: Yeah sure thanks man